# Regarding checking in Map that there should be no null key in Map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

In an interview it was being asked that whether an hash Map can store null as key and I replied yes since we can store null as key in HashMap then he further asks let say an HasMap is created consist of String as Key and its assosciated value is there , now he does not want in any case that null should be store as a key then what precheck need to be done in order to achieve that, Please advise..
below is the HashMap..

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("ty" ,"Spring");
map.put(null, "nullkey");
map.put("Anupam", "Hibernate");
map.put("Ravi", ".Net");
```

As shown above null key is there in the above Map which we don't want , what precheck need to be done so that np key should be there as Null in HashMap.  Please advise.

Comment: Empty String is not null.

Comment: If only there were some way to `iterate` through the `keys` of a hash map....

Comment: @RohitJain yeah sorry it is already been edited. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` does in fact allow null keys.

Other `Map` implementations do not, like `Hashtable` and `ConcurrentHashMap` and will throw NullPointerException if you attempt to add a null key.

If you wanted to prohibit null keys, you could either use one of these implementations, *or* your own subclass of HashMap.

Something like this:

```
public class MyHashMap extends HashMap<K,V> {
   @Override
   public V put(K key, V value) {
     if (key == null) { 
       throw new NullPointerException(); 
     }
     return super.put(key, value);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your hashmap and look for the values:

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry dataPair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(dataPair.getKey() + " : " + dataPair.getValue());
}
```

Then if you want to delete or make some operation with the key of your map, then, inside the while block:

```
if (dataPair.getKey() == null) { //Todo: Do something here}
```